# Windows password and groups

Tags: java, windows

Is it possible to change user password and/or group using Java.

The user who is running the java code have administrator privileges.

And can using java obtain list of windows users.

Answer (score 4):

An easier way to change a users password is using the `Runtime` class.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("net user someUsername somePassword");
```

And you can add or remove groups using the `net localgroup` windows command.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("net localgroup someGroup someUser /add");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("net localgroup someGroup someUser /delete");
```

To check if the command was successful or not, the `exec` method returns a `Process` object. You can read from it's Error and Input streams to get the commands output.

```
Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("net user someUsername somePassword");
BufferedReader bre = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pro.getErrorStream()));
BufferedReader bri = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pro.getInputStream()));
pro.waitFor(); //wait for the command to finish
String line;
while((line = bre.readLine()) != null)
    System.out.println(bre.readLine());
while((line = bri.readLine()) != null)
    System.out.println(bri.readLine());
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the author's intent? Windows-only commands?

Comment: @D.R. The question is tagged with [tag:windows] and mentioned Windows in the body, so I'd assume so.

Comment: Still, I'd always be unhappy with a solution which instead of using an official API relies on spooky cmd commands.

Comment: There is no official API to do these commands (not via windows anyway). The only other way would be if the author was using an Active Directory server and you were to modify users and groups via JNDI, but it seems unlikely to me that this is what the author really wants given the way the question is stated. I agree it's not the ideal solution, but for changing a native windows user's password, it's really the only one.

Answer (score 0):

There is a console command `net user`, which can be used to change user passwords.
The command is `net user userName newPassword`.
use `Desktop.getDesktop().open("file name");` // find the path to that `net` command.
Find a better way to execute if you can.